# Compressing an object in memory with System.IO.Compression in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, zip, compression

I'm trying to serialize an instance of a class (let's call it Car) into an xml and compress it in memory to a zip file with a single file entry in it.
I'm using the System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive class to do it:

```
private byte[] CompressCar(Car car)
{
    using (var carStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car)).Serialize(carStream, car);
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry("car.xml", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        using (var zippedFileStream = entry.Open())
        {
            carStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            carStream.CopyTo(zippedFileStream);
        }
        return zipStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

When I save the compressed bytes to a file and later try to open it with Windows Explorer I get an error: 
[image]
What am I doing wrong here?

I looked for other StackOverflow entries but I just couldn't find anything that would solve my problem. I want to compress it in memory rather than using a temporary file.

Comment: 1) You're serializing something called `flight` to your `carStream`.  Shouldn't you be serializing `car`?  2) Try disposing `archive` before returning `zipStream.ToArray()` (i.e move the return statement outside the innermost `using`).

Comment: Incidentally, why not serialize directly to `zippedFileStream` using `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car)).Serialize(zippedFileStream, car);` eliminating the intermediate `carStream` entirely?

Comment: You're both right. I disposed the ZipArchive object before calling ToArray() and now it works fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, I'll add a quick answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dispose the `ZipArchive` before returning the underlying `zipStream.ToArray()`.  E.g., you could extract the following helper method:

```
public static class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static byte[] ToCompressedXmlZipArchive<T>(T root, string entryName)
    {
        using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                using (var zippedFileStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(zippedFileStream, root); // Possibly use root.GetType() instead of typeof(T)
                }
            }
            return zipStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And then your method becomes:

```
    private byte[] CompressCar(Car car)
    {
        return SerializationExtensions.ToCompressedXmlZipArchive(car, "car.xml");
    }
```